# join in elastic search

Tags: join, elasticsearch

Currently I need to implement a join using elastic search, and here is the scenario:

Let's say each entry in elastic search has three fields: id, name and hobby. And given two names ('John' and 'Mary' for example), basically I want to get all the John and Mary that share the same hobby(it may differ).

Here is the possible result:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'john', hobby: 'singing'},
 {id: 2, name: 'mary', hobby: 'singing'},
 {id: 3, name: 'mary', hobby: 'singing'},
 {id: 4, name: 'john', hobby: 'cycling'},
 {id: 5, name: 'john', hobby: 'cycling'},
 {id: 6, name: 'mary', hobby: 'cycling'}
]
```

I know I can do multiple queries and do the join locally, but I'm wondering if elastic search can handle this case internally.

I'm designing a mapping to support this feature from scratch, so any suggestion is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't combine your search term into a single query, you can use [dis_max](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html) function to create a union of subqueries.

```
{
    "dis_max" : {
        "tie_breaker" : 0.7,
        "boost" : 1.2,
        "queries" : [
            {
                "term" : { "name" : "john" }
            },
            {
                "term" : { "name" : "mary" }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```